# REG_EXTRACT and REG_REPLACE in ICDI

Tags: json, regex, informatica-cloud

I'm using Informatica Cloud - ICDI mapping to process JSON data.

I have a JSON file with content as below.

```
[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:10,b:20,c:30,d:40},{a:100,b:200,c:300,d:400}]
```

I have this full JSON data in a string port in expression transformation. Now I want to extract the value with key or just the value for a and c from this string. How to use the REG_EXTRACT function to get all matches as output? Or how to use REG_REPLACE to eliminate the rest of the characters to get the desired output.

Expected Output: Comma and colon in the output are optional.

```
a:1,c:3,a:10,c:30,a:100,c:300
```

Comment: You should generally shy away from parsing JSON using regex alone.  Instead, use a JSON parsing tool designed for that job.

Comment: Okay forget JSON. Simply how to extract the required string from the input string if there are multiple matches? I want all the matches as output.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xjdzLk/3)

Where I used this regex `(?<a>a:(?<av>[^,]+))[^c]+(?<c>c:(?<cv>[^,]+))`

You get the group `a` which contains the hole a-part with value of the current block, the group `av` which contains just the value of this part and the same stuff for `c` and `cv`

Comment: This may be a valid regular expression. But I'm looking for the REG_EXTRACT() formula to used in an expression transformation of ICDI mapping to get the desired result.